# Is there an automated procedure to upload mails from Outlook/Outlook Express to Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-server-2007

I'm moving an organization from pop3 accounts to Microsoft Exchange 2007, and I have to upload all the users mails (which are in, mostly, Outlook Express and a few Outlook) to their Exchange accounts. 
Anybody knows an automated or semi-automated procedure to upload all the mails and address books from Outlook Express and from a .pst file without having to configure the account in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading per se is not the problem, this can be easily achieved using the WebDav protocol on the Exchange web access.

However, getting the mails out of the PST and PBX (I think the file is for OE) may be more difficult, while I know that some file format descriptions exist, this may still be the most difficult part.

Answer (score 0):

You have solutions for those problems (address books and e-mails) with some extra scripting, and both are free.

1. With [Outlook Express API Standard](http://www.nektra.com/products/oeapi-windows-mail-outlook-express-plugin/download) you can quickly develop a script to upload e-mails to Microsoft Exchange.
2. With NKTWAB (LGPL) you can retrieve the WAB contacts and store them on Exchange.
3. On Outlook is pretty straightforward since it has an API.